# Microsoft Expression SDK

Tags: c#

I'm converting mp3 to wma with expression encoder sdk 4 with the code below

A wma file is produced but it is missing the thumbnail / image / cover from the mp3 file.

```
using (var job = new Job())
{
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem(input.FullName)
            {
                 OutputFileName = outputFileName,
                 OutputFormat =
                         {
                             AudioProfile =
                             {
                                 Codec = AudioCodec.Wma,
                                 Bitrate = BitRate ?? BitRate,
                                 Channels = 1
                             }
                         }
            };


    job.MediaItems.Add(mediaItem);

    job.OutputDirectory = OutputDirectory;
    job.CreateSubfolder = false;
    job.Encode();
}
```

I have tried the following:

1)

```
mediaItem.MarkerThumbnailCodec = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
mediaItem.MarkerThumbnailJpegCompression = 0;
mediaItem.MarkerThumbnailSize = new Size(50, 50);
```

2)

```
mediaItem.ThumbnailCodec = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
mediaItem.ThumbnailEmbed = true;
mediaItem.ThumbnailJpegCompression = 50;
mediaItem.ThumbnailMode = ThumbnailMode.BestFrame;
mediaItem.ThumbnailSize = new Size(50, 50);
mediaItem.ThumbnailTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
```

3)

```
mediaItem.OverlayFileName = @"c:\Chrysanthemum.jpg";
mediaItem.OverlayStartTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
```

..but it doesn't help.

Please help me :)